# Kotlin-List collection

Tags: kotlin, collections

I came across this code for creating a list. `val listNumbers = List(readln().toInt()) { readln().toInt() }`.
As I know (a very beginner to Kotlin programming), we make list through functions, listOf() or toMutableList(). The above code looks different (List()). Could someone please explain. Would appreciate.

Comment: Why not check the documentation first? See: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/constructing-collections.html#initializer-functions-for-lists

Comment: Thanks! got it. Normally when I look online most of the sites suggest to make list with listOf() or toList(). Never knowing that there is a constructor-like function. Thanks once again!